# Prove that there is no finite Borel measure $\mu$ such that set of$\mu$ negligible sets equal the set of meager set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $([0,1],B([0,1]),\mu)$ is a measure space, here $B([0,1])$ is the set of all Borel sets on [0,1], let $N_{\mu}$ be the set of all subset S of $[0,1]$ such that S is $\mu$-negligible, let $M$ be the set of all meager sets contained in $[0,1]$, I want to show that there is no finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ such that $N_{\mu}=M$, how to show this? can anyone help me? thank you in advance

Comment: Coutnable sets have  measure $0$, so $\mu$ is non-atomic. Just mimic the construction of fat Cantor set using $\mu$ in place of Lebesgue measure. You wil get a n--where dense set with positive measure.

Comment: This is a nice question, because it highlights that the "orthogonality" between the concepts of null set and meager set is not only valid for the Lebesgue measure in $[0,1]$, but it actually applies to any finite measure in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @YuerWu I believe the closing votes are because you did not clearly indicate what you had tried.  I suggest you include your attempts in your question (even if they were very basic and incomplete).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132221/discussion-on-question-by-yuerwu-prove-that-there-is-no-finite-borel-measure-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First step:** If there is a point $x\in [0,1]$ such that $\mu(\{x\})>0$, then we have a meager set (namely $\{x\}$) of positive measure.

**Second step:** Suppose that for all $x\in [0,1]$, $\mu(\{x\})=0$. Then, since $\mu$ is finite, for any sequence of open intervals $\{U_n\}_n$ such that $\{x\}= \bigcap_n U_n$, we have $\lim_n \mu(U_n) =0$.

So we can mimic the excellent answer by Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen in MO for the case of Lebesgue measure (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43478/is-there-a-measure-zero-set-which-isnt-meagre/43480#43480)):

Let $p_i$ be a list of the rational numbers. Let $U_{i,n}$ be an open interval centered on $p_i$ such that $\mu(U_{i,n})<2^{-i}/n$. Then $V_n=\cup_i U_{i,n}$ is an open cover of the rationals, of measure at most $\sum_i 2^{-i}/n=2/n$. Then $\cap_n V_n$ is a co-meager set of measure zero. By Baire Category Theorem, $\cap_n V_n$ is not meager.

So yes, there is a measure zero set that is not meager, and so no, not every measure zero set is meager.

**Remark:** For the second step above, Kavi Rama Murphy'suggestion is also fine:  mimicing the construction of fat Cantor set using $\mu$, instead of the Lebesgue measure, will produce a set $C$ closed and nowhere dense (so meager) such that $\mu(C)>0$.

Comment: This is a reminder to refrain from answering low-quality/[problem-statement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/what-is-a-psq) questions, as outlined in [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: Why the downvote?  The answer is correct and complete.